# Mongo - findAndModify has to be executed twice to take effect

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `campaign` like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec12c501bd23866ef315a85"),
        "schemaVersion" : "1",
        "internalVersion" : NumberLong(56),
        "code" : "CK",
        "siteCampaigns" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f3689274d42720edb5be328"),
                        "siteCode" : "IT",
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T06:00:00Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-20T06:00:00Z"),
                        "status" : "SUBSCRIBED"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f3689274d42720edb5be327"),
                        "siteCode" : "ES",
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T06:00:00Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-02-20T06:00:00Z"),
                        "status" : "UNSUBSCRIBED"
                },
                ...
            ]
}
```

Now I want to find and modify the element in the `siteCampaigns`.

I use this query:

```
db.campaign.findAndModify({
    query: {
        code: "CK", 'siteCampaigns.siteCode': "IT"
    }, 
    update: {
        "$set": {
            'siteCampaigns.$.endDate': ISODate("2020-08-30T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }, 
    upsert:false
})
```

I execute it for the first time, I find the document, no error, but the field is not modified; when I repeat it, it finds the same document, now updated.

I always have to execute it twice to take effect. Why? I use mongo shell.

Comment: The output/error message from both the failed and successful attempt would help determine what is going on.

Comment: No, no error; I just find the document for the 1st time, and I repeated the same query, and the doc is modified. That's the strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

Find the doc..

> The 'findAndModify' command modifies and returns a single document. By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update. To return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the `new` option.

About `new`:

> Optional. When true, returns the modified document rather than the original. The findAndModify method ignores the new option for remove operations. The default is false. |

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/

So I should have done:

```
db.campaign.findAndModify({
    query: {
        code: "CK", 'siteCampaigns.siteCode': "IT"
    }, 
    update: {
        "$set": {
            'siteCampaigns.$.endDate': ISODate("2020-08-30T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }, 
    upsert:false,
    new: true
})
```